# Files deleted automatically in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel website and unfortunately, under the `storage/framework` folder, we have `cache sessions` testing views folder.

The day before yesterday I came to office and found `sessions`, `testing` and `views` folder are deleted.

I have checked the error log and I found nothing.So, I just reset the git commit and my site was online.

Anyone has any idea how these folders are deleted automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Expired sessions are deleted regularly by Laravel too keep the folder clean.

However, you should not depend on anything in the `storage/framework` folder. This is where the Laravel framework itself stores compiled or temporary files that are needed to use the features in the framework. It's possible that something changes in a newer version of Laravel and the directory is used in another way.

How Laravel uses these folders should not impact your application.